# Get mysqli query as a string

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I am working on a project that requires a user to log in using an email address and a password. Doing that, I must test if the password the person has entered to see if it matches the one located in the database. I'm trying to get the MySQLi query (`SELECT password FROM users WHERE email='$email_login'`) in a way I can compaire it using password_verify(). I have this PHP/MySQLi code:

```
$email_login = $_POST["email_login"];
$pass_login = $_POST["pass_login"];
if(isset($_POST["email_login"]) && isset($_POST["pass_login"])) {

        $sql_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT password FROM users WHERE email='$email_login'");
        $pass_query = print_r($sql_query, 1);
        echo $pass_query;
        $pass_test= password_verify($pass_login, $pass_query);

        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email_login' AND password='$pass_test' LIMIT 1");

        $userCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
        if($userCount == 1) {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                            $id = row["id"];
                }
                $_SESSION["email_login"] = $email_login;
                header("Location: index.php");
                exit();
        } else {
                echo "It looks like you have an issue with your credentials.";
                exit();
        }
}
```

Schema of database

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
id | first_name | last_name | username | email          | password |

1    John         Doe         john17     john@gmail.com   (hashed)
```

and here is the form:

```
        <h1>Sign in</h1>
        <form class="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
            <input type="email" name="email_login" size="25" placeholder="Email address" required>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="password" name="pass_login" placeholder="Password" required>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
        </form>
```

Everything works as it should, except for the two password_verify() lines. To try and figure out what is wrong, I printed the `$pass_test` variable as a string using print_r() and got this:

```
mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )
```

Is there a safe way where I can get the result of a mysqli query in a form that can be tested using password_verify()?

Comment: I bet this code is from some online tutorial. I have a feeling I've seen something of the kind already. And I have to say that it's a VERY bad tutorial.

Comment: You need to `fetch`. This is open to SQL injections.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Actually, I have been working on this while watching a tutorial on YouTube, and it is very outdated. I've just been using it as an example at this point while using more up-to-date php/mysqli.

Comment: 1. Hash the passwords, 2. Use prepare statements 3. Get a better tutorial.

Comment: While good advice above, not really helpful. Maybe a link to a better tutorial or add one as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Did you notice that row inside of while loop missing '$' sign.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                            $id = $row["id"];
                                  ^     /*missing '$'

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a quick check try putting `$pass_login` in double quotes. See the first comment [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) in the documentation.

Second, I think you're making this more complicated than you need. I think all you need is this:

```
$pass_login = password_hash ($_POST["pass_login"]);

$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email_login' AND password="$pass_login" LIMIT 1");
```

If you get a false return it's a failed login, otherwise . . .

**Update:**

So, now that I've had more time to look at this here's what I came up with as a working example. I've written this in Object Oriented style:

First, when entering the user hash their password input before saving:

```
$hashed_pass = password_hash("john17", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Make sure you're connected

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(yadda, yadda, yadda);//obviously, your credentials here
if (!$conn) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($conn) . PHP_EOL;

/*This checks the password on login so as long as your $_POST variables are set from your form you should be all set: */

$_POST["email_login"] = 'john@gmail.com';
$_POST["pass_login"] = "john17";

$email_login = $_POST["email_login"];
$pass_login = $_POST["pass_login"];


if(isset($_POST["email_login"]) && isset($_POST["pass_login"] ) ) {

    if ($result = $conn->query("SELECT password FROM test_table WHERE email='$email_login'")) {

        printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);
        $userCount = $result->num_rows;

        if($userCount == 1) {

            while($user_array = $result->fetch_array()){ 
                //var_dump($user_array);
                $saved_hashed_pass = $user_array[0];
                $auth = password_verify($_POST["pass_login"], $saved_hashed_pass );
                if( $auth === true ) {
                    echo "It looks like you are approved";
                    //$_SESSION["email_login"] = $email_login;
                    //header("Location: index.php");
                } else {

                    echo "It looks like you have an issue with your credentials.";
                    exit();
                }

            }   

        } else {
            echo "It looks like you have an issue with your credentials.";
            //exit();
        }

        /* free result set */
        $result->close();
    } else {
        printf("Error: %s\n", $conn->error);
 }
```

Comment: It is interesting that you neither understands how password_hash works nor what does the first comment mean. Which makes both your suggestions wrong.

Comment: Any help? You seem to know a lot about this.